# Starting an Android init.rc service from an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, init

Before I start, this is meant for our own android based device and not for a phone nor for deployment elsewhere.

We have a service in init.rc that is a postgresql database server. This launches on startup and always runs in the background for the system. There's the possibility that it might close however and we would like to have a way to stop and start this service from the android side of the system.

Is there a way to send an init start command from an android Activity? From a root shell, this would be the equivalent of running "start servicename" and "stop servicename".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To start a service which is declared in the init.rc file, i think you must change the "ctl.start" system property with following commands :

In c file :

```
property_set("ctl.start", "<service_name>");
```

In java :

```
SystemProperties.set("ctl.start", "<service_name>");
```

This implies that your activity has system permissions (in the manifest) :

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

and is signed by your system key (or put platform in the Android.mk)

As you can guess, to stop the service use following commands :

```
property_set("ctl.stop", "<service_name>");
```

or

```
SystemProperties.set("ctl.stop", "<service_name>");
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this until now. By "put platform in the Android.mk" is that something that is only for C apps running on Android? And for the System key, does that mean that you have to build the APK separately for every system that you would be deploying it to?

Comment: I'm guessing by the system key, that means that we would need to actually build the entire android system for the hardware if we wanted to utilize this method to start our service. I think that would make it mostly useless for our needs at the moment, because we don't have enough of the drivers for the hardware to build it ourselves and we're relying on the manufacturer of the SoM to build it. Thanks for the answer however. I'll check with the manufacturer of the SoM and see if they can gives us a more complete build tree with the drivers included.